# Where does socket store data?

Tags: linux, sockets, tcp

We have TCP socket connection, from my computer to remote address.

Please, clarify me the next points:

1. When socket TCP connection is done, the port on client is opened, and also the port on server is opened ?
2. I want to understand where sockets keep the data when we write something to socket ? We have two same files on server and client ? Or data stored in RAM memory ?
3. If data are stored in files, can I found files on linux, especially on ubuntu 18.04 ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 1. When socket TCP connection is done, the port on client is opened, and also the port on server is opened ?

Yes.

> 2. I want to understand where sockets keep the data when we write something to socket ? We have two same files on server and client ? Or data stored in RAM memory ?

You cannot have the same file on server and client unless they are both on the same machine. But even if they are, the entire data is kept in memory per socket: one buffer for incoming data and one buffer for outgoing. When new data comes the OS buffers it until the app calls .read(). Note that this is an implementation detail.

> 3. If data are stored in files, can I found files on linux, especially on ubuntu 18.04 ?

It is not in files.

Comment: Yes, that's precisely what I've just written.

Comment: Thank u very much! Last question: is there used a practice to clear the ram or buffer ? Because I faced with RAM leaking

Comment: No, there is no such practice. And you should never do that, it can break stuff in so many unpredictable ways. Whatever you experience, it is most likely a bug in your application.

Comment: so therefore, after I read data from socket, RAM must be cleared, right ? Or at some moment it must be cleared automatically. Since you said I have not to clear it

Comment: @Mikael Buffers always take some memory. They are alive as long as the socket is alive. But buffers don't take much memory. Something around 16kb per socket by default I think (and I also think this is configurable). Once you .close() the socket the OS will free the memory. It is crucial to always close() no longer needed file descriptors.